# Make sprite face cursor in Dark GDK

Tags: c++

I have been working on a Dark GDK project in which I make a sprite face the cursor or mouse's location. I picked up on some code and implemented it into my application but it seems to not be working correction. Here is a preview, http://gyazo.com/bf57df49071e3a684a7e03b8f0cf4527, as you can see, the sprite is not facing the right place where the cursor is and it does not move correctly. I believe this is because Dark GDK doesn't know where the center of my object is. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? I changed the values of the rotation and rotated the sprite but that didn't help at all.

```
 // Dark GDK - The Game Creators - www.thegamecreators.com

 // the wizard has created a very simple project that uses Dark GDK
 // it contains the basic code for a GDK application

 // whenever using Dark GDK you must ensure you include the header file
#include "DarkGDK.h"


// the main entry point for the application is this function
void DarkGDK ( void )
{
// turn on sync rate and set maximum rate to 60 fps
dbSyncOn   ( );
dbSyncRate ( 60 );
dbLoadImage("hero.png", 1);
dbSprite(1,100,100,1);
// our main loop

while ( LoopGDK ( ) )
{

    float dx = dbMouseX() - dbSpriteX(1);
    float dy = dbMouseY() - dbSpriteY(1);
    dbRotateSprite(1,dbAtanFull(dy,dx));


    if(dbEscapeKey() == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    dbSync ( );
}



dbDeleteImage(1);
dbDeleteSprite(1);
// return back to windows
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The Sprite' Axis of Rotation Is At The Point Where It Is Drawn From The Upper-Left Hand Corner. That Axis Can Be Changed Using:

```
                      dbOffsetSprite( iD , xOff , yOff );
```

From the picture the preferred offset point would be the center of the ball.

2) The side/edge of the image (top,left,right,bottom) that face the cursor will be the 0 degree side. On any sprite the axis is:............................................
                                         90 ...............................................................................................
                                          .........................................................................|
                                     ..................................................................................................................................................................180--o--0.............................................................................................
                                          .........................................................................|..................................................................................................
                                          .......................................................................270....................................................................................... 
Using the setup above the 0 will always face the cursor.

3.) To get the corresponding angle to face the cursor, simply add(+) that angle inside the function:

```
                     dbRotateSprite( 1 , dbAtanFull(dy,dx) + 90.0 );
```